# How do I query via a specific adapter in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have an app that needs to combine the REST api from multiple hosts

currently I have

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
    namespace: 'api/v1'
```

and I would like to do something like

```
App.FooAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
    namespace: 'api/v1'
    host:  'http://myserver.com'

App.BarAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
    namespace: 'api/v1'
    host:  'http://myotherserver.com'
```

I have attempted to change

```
this.get('store').findAll('post')
```

which works fine to

```
this.get('Foo') ... etc or
this.get('FooAdapter')... etc
```

but are getting

cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined. How do I refer to a specific adapter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably define a single adapter, then define what `find` and `findAll` do.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({

  findAll: function(store, type, id) {
    var url1 = 'http://myserver.com',
        url2 = 'http://myotherserver.com';

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Em.RSVP.all([
        jQuery.getJSON(url1),
        jQuery.getJSON(url2)
      ]).then(function(arr) {
        // arr is an array containing the responses from your AJAX requests
        var someData = arr[0],
            otherData = arr[1];

        // Munge the data to get what you need for your model
        var modelData = ...

        // then return it from the method. ED will instantiate the appropriate
        // model using your data
        Ember.run(null, resolve, modelData);

      }, function(jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.then = null; // tame jQuery's ill mannered promises
        Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR);
      });
    });
  },

  find: ...
});
```

You'll want to use `type` to specify the URL for different models. Or, you can define separate adapters for each model.

You may also want to read [the guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/) to learn more about custom adapters.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the separate adapters for each model.